# R - Consolidate date data in different rows into "days from date" list

Tags: r, date, merge

I'm new to R and am working on a project in which I collect data from various experimental groups on ongoing dates in a master spreadsheet and would like to compare the data for each group in R based on the number of days from a start date that the reading occurs for all groups.

My data looks like this:

```
Experiment Mouse start_date 2/1/2017 2/2/2017 . . . 3/1/2017 3/2/2017
1 1 2/1/2017 25 26 . . .  22 21
2 2 3/1/2017 n/a n/a . . . 25 27
```

where ". . ." is most dates in between 2/2/2017 and 3/1/2017.

My goal would be to convert this into a format such as:

```
Experiment Mouse Day1 Day2  . . . Day29 Day30
1 1 25 26 . . . 22 21 
2 2 25 27 . . . n/a n/a
```

I figured out how to add dataframe columns of dates, but because these dates are in different rows, I wasn't sure how to consolidate these rows in this way.

Thanks!

Comment: What file format is your original data?

Comment: I've been importing it as a csv

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, you could use `read.csv`, defining the desired names of your columns using the `col.names` argument. Is this what are you trying to achieve?